# Javascript only works after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

The meta tag is in the head of the page and the javascript is after jQuery at the end of the document. When I run the code from Chrome's console it works fine and sortList is set to `[[0,0]]` just as I expect but when it's run on the page I get an exception in the console. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'date' in undefined(anonymous function)`

HTML

```
<meta data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_SORT" data-content="date">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'list')
        var sortCodes = {'date': 0, 'show': 1, 'network': 4};
        var sort = $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_SORT"]').data('content');
        var sortList = (sort in sortCodes) ? [[sortCodes[sort], 0]] : [[0, 0]]; 

    if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'banner' || $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'poster')
        $('#sbRoot').ajaxEpSearch({'size': 16, 'loadingImage': 'loading16' + themeSpinner + '.gif'});
        $('.ep_summary').hide();
        $('.ep_summaryTrigger').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.ep_summary').slideToggle('normal', function() {
                $(this).prev('.ep_summaryTrigger').attr('src', function(i, src) {
                    return $(this).next('.ep_summary').is(':visible') ? src.replace('plus','minus') : src.replace('minus','plus')
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: of course it works only after the page is loaded :) try `window.onload = yourFunction;`

Comment: for consistent results, do it in a jqueery document ready block

Comment: @JaromandaX: No, if jQuery is at the end of the document (which the OP says it is), there's no need for `ready`.

Comment: @webduvet: The OP said their jQuery and JavaScript are at the end of the document; using `onload` is not indicated here.

Comment: How to reproduce this issue ? There is no way `sortCodes` could be `undefined` I suppose..

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't have enough information in it for us to answer. You'll need to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, ideally using a Stack Snippet (`<>`) if you can replicate the problem in that environment, or something we can copy and paste to work with.

Comment: Jaromanda it's inside a document load block, there's a lot more code but I don't think that's the reason it's not working.

Comment: Unrelated: If all you're doing is getting the value of the attribute, `data` is overkill. Use `.attr("data-content")` instead. `data` does a lot more than just get the attribute: http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: I should point out to @T.J.Crowder that I make a copy of your SO standard responses (in this case MCVE) so that I don't have to cobble together something from the help section each time :)

Comment: It'd be nice to be given a second to reply before people start downvoting this, far out!

Comment: I think the other one is "Welcome to Stack Overflow something something..."

Comment: @Andy: I have three of those on speeddial (well, bookmarklet). The above is a one-off, but I type pretty fast. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can add, I've updated the code to show the full part of the script I'm refering to. I've also linked to the full javascript file.

Comment: I have a feeling it's not something that'll show up on a MCVE and that's why I didn't bother making one. Like I said, this works fine in Chrome's console but not when the page loads.

Comment: in the html where jqueery and your script is loaded, you don't do anything stupid like defer or load jqueery AFTER your script? because I just "dummied" up a page, and it works fine, don't even need a document load block

Comment: No, not that I know of. Here's a gist of the whole page rendered, I honestly can't think of anything that could be causing this. https://gist.github.com/OmgImAlexis/66f2a477b85e8b8c97b3

Comment: I'm assuming that's a copy/paste error at the end of line 5 in your example. Also, the link to the full code has no resemblance to the code you posted here.

Comment: Andy I fixed to copy/paste error and the full link.

Comment: @XO, it must be somewhere else in the code because your posted code doesn't have references to `date in something` anywhere I can see.

Comment: 'date' is what sort is set to once the page loads, that's what the meta tag does.

Comment: @XO: *"Here's the full file in question."* Questions relying on external content are not appropriate for SO. If you think the full file is relevant, quote the full file **in** the question. If you don't, don't link it. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: T.J. It does have that, I forgot to update the meta tag on there when I changed the rest. I removed sickbeard. when I was testing in case there was a problem with it containing a dot.

Comment: Should I just close this then? Doesn't seem like you guys want to help me at all which is what I thought SO is about. I added the external link for clarification. It's also a link to a github file which hardly ever get deleted so there's almost no chance of link rot.

Comment: @XO: The code you've actually posted to the question replicates the issue for me using Chrome. It is **bizarre** and I'm trying to figure it out. So the question stands on its own and you can just remove that link.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the link. Like I said I've tried different things by removing the dot, moving the whole script into a single file. Moved jQuery above and below the script. Nothing seems to fix this and I don't understand why when the sort variable is set just above it so there's no reason it should be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing a block on your `if` and your indentation is lying to you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // MISSING { HERE --------------------------------------------------------------v
    if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'list')
        var sortCodes = {'date': 0, 'show': 1, 'network': 4};
        var sort = $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_SORT"]').data('content');
        var sortList = (sort in sortCodes) ? [[sortCodes[sort], 0]] : [[0, 0]]; 

    if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'banner' || $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'poster')
        $('#sbRoot').ajaxEpSearch({'size': 16, 'loadingImage': 'loading16' + themeSpinner + '.gif'});
        $('.ep_summary').hide();
        $('.ep_summaryTrigger').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.ep_summary').slideToggle('normal', function() {
                $(this).prev('.ep_summaryTrigger').attr('src', function(i, src) {
                    return $(this).next('.ep_summary').is(':visible') ? src.replace('plus','minus') : src.replace('minus','plus')
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Consequently, the line following only applies if the `if` condition is true. What you really have is:

```
if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'list')
    var sortCodes = {'date': 0, 'show': 1, 'network': 4};
var sort = $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_SORT"]').data('content');
var sortList = (sort in sortCodes) ? [[sortCodes[sort], 0]] : [[0, 0]];
```

So if the `if` condition is false, `sortCodes` is `undefined`.

What you probably *wanted* was:

```
if($('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_LAYOUT"]').data('content') == 'list') {
    var sortCodes = {'date': 0, 'show': 1, 'network': 4};
    var sort = $('meta[data-var="sickbeard.COMING_EPS_SORT"]').data('content');
    var sortList = (sort in sortCodes) ? [[sortCodes[sort], 0]] : [[0, 0]]; 
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it's a soft tab vs hard tab issue then?

Comment: @XO: JavaScript doesn't care about soft vs. hard tabs. This is Yet Another Example of how not always using blocks after control statements can bite you and waste your time.

Comment: Javascript doesn't but my editor does and that'd explain why it shows as being correctly inline and yet it's not. I'm going to add control statements now.